# Splunk comparison in lookup tables and display output

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have 2 lookup files as

1. lookup1.csv and
2. lookup2.csv

lookup1.csv has the data as below

```
name, designation, server, ipaddress, dept
tim, ceo, hostname.com, 1.2.3.5, alldept
jim, vp, myhost.com, 1.0.3.5, marketing
pim, staff, nohost.com, 4.0.4.8, hr
```

lookup2.csv has the data as below

```
cidr, location
1.2.3.0/24, dc
1.0.3.0/24, carolina
3.4.7.0/24, tx
```

I would like to lookup for the field ipaddress in lookup1.csv with the field cidr in lookup2.csv for the first 3 digits as in x.x.x and get the location field if they match. If the ipaddress doesn't match the first 3 digit of cidr , the location should be marked as "unknown".

Expected o/p

```
tim, ceo,1.2.4.5, dc
jim, vp, 1.0.3.5, carolina
pim, staff, 4.0.4.8, unkown
```

I am looking for the search command in splunk using the 2 lookup tables. Thanks in advance. My search so far has not yield any good results but I am still working on it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you enabled CIRDMATCH() on lookup2.csv in a [Lookup Definition](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Lookupdefinition)? Or via the [`cidrmatch`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/ConditionalFunctions#lookup.28.26lt.3Blookup_table.26gt.3B.2C.26lt.3Bjson_object.26gt.3B.2C.26lt.3Bjson_array.26gt.3B.29) command?

Comment: Got help from another expert and using CIDR(cidr) in the lookup. This is working for me so far.  Working on to display an "unknow" value when lookup doesn't exists. | inputlookup lookup1.csv
| lookup lookup2.csv cidr AS ipaddress OUTPUT location
| table name designation server ipaddress dept location

Answer (score 1):

Use the `isnull()` function to determine if the `lookup` was successful or not.

```
| inputlookup lookup1.csv 
| lookup lookup2.csv cidr AS ipaddress OUTPUT location 
| eval location=if(isnull(location), "unknown", location)
| table name designation server ipaddress dept location
```

Comment: Thanks @RichG. I was using fillNull but this looks more better.

Comment: @Bond - honestly ...`fillnull value="unknown"` is simpler to write. But RichG's suggestion to `eval if...` is more *obvious* in what it is doing :)